# Trying to flatten a Reddit JSON into many "conversations"

Tags: python, list, recursion, reddit, flatten

I am trying to use the comments of Reddit threads as a training set for a machine learning program. An example of an input would be https://old.reddit.com/r/bayarea/comments/cxxl9y/billionaires_yacht_docked_in_embarcadero.json.

I am filtering out the body, id, and parent_id in hopes of turning the nested JSON into many conversations.

For example, if the input is `["A", ["B",["C", "D"]]]`, the output should be `["A", "B", "C"], ["A","B","D"]`.

Below is my current code:

```
json_url = "https://old.reddit.com/r/bayarea/comments/cxxl9y/billionaires_yacht_docked_in_embarcadero.json"
            r = requests.get(json_url, headers={"user-agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.15.2"})

            comments_tree_raw = fltr(r.json(), ["ups", "body", "id", "parent_id"])[1]["data"]

            comments_tree_raw = flatten([], comments_tree_raw["children"])
```

```
def remove_all_after(node, index):
    target = node.index(index)
    return node[:target]




training_threads = []
# input the children list
def flatten(output, children):
    global training_threads


    for child in children:
        try:
            child_obj = child["data"] if "body" in child["data"] else child
            child_comment = {
                "body": child_obj["body"],
                "id": child_obj["id"],
                "parent": child_obj["parent_id"]
            }
            output.append(child_comment)
        except KeyError:
            continue

        if "replies" not in child["data"]:

            training_threads.append(output.copy())

            parent_id = child_comment["parent"].split("_")[1]
            for i in output:
                if i["id"] == parent_id:
                    output = remove_all_after(output, i)
                    break


            continue

        flatten(output, child["data"]["replies"]["data"]["children"])
```

Here, I am trying to solve the problem recursively, but it isn't producing the output I need. This is the output I am getting:  https://pastebin.com/GkpwGUtK.

Would greatly appreciate the help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple recursion with a generator:

```
data = ["A", ["B",["C", "D"]]]
def group(d, c = []):
   a, b = d
   if all(not isinstance(i, list) for i in b):
     yield from [c+[a, i] for i in b]
   else:
     yield from group(b, c+[a])

print(list(group(data)))
```

Output:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'D']]
```

---

Edit: more complete version using `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
def group(d, c = []):
  _d = [list(b) for _, b in groupby(d, key=lambda x:isinstance(x, list))]
  if len(_d) == 1:
    for i in _d[0]:
      if not isinstance(i, list):
         yield c+[i]
      else:
         yield from group(i, c)
  else:
     for i in range(0, len(_d), 2):
       for k in _d[i]:
         yield from group(_d[i+1], c+[k])

print(list(group([["C", ["D", "E"], ["C", ["D", "E"], ["C", ["D", "E"]]]]])))
```

Output:

```
[['C', 'D'], ['C', 'E'], ['C', 'C', 'D'], ['C', 'C', 'E'], ['C', 'C', 'C', 'D'], ['C', 'C', 'C', 'E']]
```

Comment: Hi @Ajax1234, it works for 2 element lists, but for anything higher than that, it gives error ```ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)``` ... is there a way to get it working in all scenarios?

Comment: @VidurGupta Can you post your new input and desired output?

Comment: so I was basically hoping for it to work in any scenario. For example, ["A", ["B",["C", "D"]]] or ["A", ["B",["C", "D", "E"]]] or any possible combinations. The API I am using isn't limited to 2-element lists. Thanks.

Comment: @VidurGupta That is strange, when I run my code on those input samples I achieve the desired output i.e for  `["A", ["B",["C", "D", "E"]]]` I get `[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'E']]`. Can you clarify? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, sorry about that. This is the exact input I was trying to get working: https://pastebin.com/zTYCUrpd. (For context, this is Reddit comment data in the hierarchy)  @ajax1234

Comment: @VidurGupta Thank you for providing the input! In the data, there are input lists that only have one element such as `['Copy that.']`. What would your desired output be for single element lists?

Comment: Apologies, I think the simplified input/output I posted was a bit unclear. Basically, if we can get those one elements, such as ["A"], ["B"], ["C", ["D", "E"]], it should output. [["A"], ["B"], ["C", "D"], ["C","E"]]. Basically I need to feed it in a machine learning program that wants separate "conversations" to learn how people interact with each other. Im sorry about the earlier confusions. I also appreciate the help!

Comment: @VidurGupta No problem, thank you for your comment. However, sometimes there are elements that have three values, rather than one or two i.e `[["C", ["D", "E"], ["C", ["D", "E"], ["C", ["D", "E"]]`. How would you like the output to be formatted for those?

Comment: so if the input is ```[
 ["C", ["D", "E"],
  ["C", ["D", "E"],
   ["C", ["D", "E"]]
  ]
 ]
]```, then the output would be ```["C", "D"], ["C", E"], ["C", "C", D"], ["C", "C", E"], ["C","C","C","D"],["C","C","C","E"] ``` For reference, i plugged in the array into http://jsonviewer.stack.hu and using it like a "nested structure".

Comment: @VidurGupta Thank you for your comment. Please see my recent edit, as I added a solution which better reflects your input data as a whole.

Comment: Awesome! This solves everything I needed, thanks so much! Brilliantly coded & works in every way!